# Send AJAX request without any cookie

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

The situation is as follows:

I am logged into a web application and there is an HTTPOnly-Cookie stored with a JSESSIONID. The backend I am sending requests to is running on the same website/url as the frontend application. Now while I am logged in as User A (identified by the cookie with the JSESSIONID), I need to do a single request to the same backend but without this cookie! Whenever I send a request to the backend, this cookie is automatically sent too though.

So how can I tell an AJAX request to NOT automatically send this certain HTTPOnly cookie - or even any cookie at all. I know that this can be achieved for Cross-Origin calls (see "withCredentials" flag). But this does not help since it is no Cross-Origin call...

Can anyone help me with this one?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: `withCredentials` flag actually allows cookies anyway

Comment: Mozilla has a [`mozAnon` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/mozAnon) - but that doesn't seem to work cross-browser.

Comment: try the new [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) - apparently it doesn't send cookies [unless you specifically want to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials)